# script client code to php webservice

Tags: php

I am really sticky on this problem  :

here is a php server side code , i wanna do a web service , the client is java script , i wrote it in php client and it worked ,, i tried many times to make client java script to call the web service from the php server according to the yii framework , can any body    give me a java script code to handle this web service in the php code down (ther is just one service getSMS)  , and if any body wanna the script code to check where the error is , i will send it  to him:

```
 ** <?php
   ini_set ('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
class WebservicesController extends Controller
 {

  /**
  * @var string the default layout for the views.
 Defaults to '//layouts/column2',         meaning
  * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
  */


  /**
  * @return array action filters
    */









  /**
  * Specifies the access control rules.
  * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
  * @return array access control rules
  */
  public function accessRules()
  {
   return 
    array('allow', 
        'actions'=>array('quote'),
        'user'=>array('*'),);


   }



    public function actions()
  {
  return array(
      'quote'=>array(
          'class'=>'CWebServiceAction',
            'classMap'=>array(
      'Sms'=>'Sms',
      )
      ),
  );
    }




       /**
      //
         * @return string
      * @soap
      */

        public function getSMS()
       {

     $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
     ->select('text')
     ->from('sms')
      ->queryall();


       return json_encode($user);






           }



    }

   class webservices extends CActiveRecord
  {
   /**
  * @var integer post ID
  * @soap
  */
 public $id;
 /**
* @var string post title
 * @soap
 */
  public $title;

  public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
  {
  return parent::model($className);
  }
   }




  ?>
```